# What could be the potential solution to display Facebook login button in a SKScene?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to an iOS game and want to show the Facebook button in a SKScene instead of UIViewController. But for some reasons the buttons are not displaying anymore and I got blank white screen! Could you please what could be the potential solution to display Facebook login button in a SKScene?

Here's the code :

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class AuthViewController: SKScene, SKViewDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {





override func didMove(to view: SKView) {





    //add facebook sign in button

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
   // addChild(loginButton)


    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 50, width: (view.frame.width) - 32, height: 50)
    loginButton.delegate = self as FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

    loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]


    //add Google sign-in button

    let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()

    googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 50 + 66, width: (view.frame.width) - 32, height: 50)

    view.addSubview(googleButton)

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self



}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("Did log out of facebook")
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)

        return
    }
    else {
        //skView.presentScene(location, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 5))



        print("Successfully logged in with facebook...")
    }

    func showEmailAddress() {

        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()

        guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }



        let credentials = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) { (user, error) in


            if error != nil {
                print("Something went wrong with our FB user: ", error ?? "")
                return
            }





            print("Successfully logged in with our users:", user ?? "")
        }


        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print("Fail to return graph request:", err ?? "")

                return
            }

            print(result ?? "")

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: That code worked before? What do you mean by white blank screen? The button only white? Can you add a simple UIButton just for testing?

Comment: That code worked before when I pasted it GameViewController however I can not transit to the Scenes from View Controller. in SpirteKit every thing is a SKScene